# Which of these two examples is a better code design?

Tags: java, swing, coding-style

**Example #1**

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    if (isShowParameters)
       isShowParameters = false;
    else
       isShowParameters = true;

    ParametersWindows.getInstance().setVisible(isShowParameters);
}
```

**Example #2**

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    isShowParameters = !isShowParameters;
    ParametersWindows.getInstance().setVisible(isShowParameters);
}
```

Comment: In both cases, the indenting is wicked.

Comment: pity should be `isShowParameters ^=true;`

Comment: This question is unclear. Are you asking how to make each example more efficient or which of the two is better code design?

Comment: @bestsss - It is cool, but not immediately clear to the person who is reading the code...

Comment: @Petar, dunno about you, to me it is clear :). It was somewhat popular construct in pascal ages ago. `ParametersWindows.getInstance().setVisible(isShowParameters^=true);` this's probably too much, though :P

Comment: @bestsss - It is also clear to me(I love hacks:P), but not to the average monkey coder:)

Comment: or `ParametersWindows.getInstance().setVisible(isShowParameters = (isShowParameters==true)  ? false : true);` or even `ParametersWindows.getInstance().setVisible(isShowParameters = (isShowParameters)  ? false : true);`

Comment: @Petar, the construct is also useful in case of like `b[i++]^=true;` or `b[calcIndex(p)+base]^=true;` otherwise need to keep the index in a temp variable.

Comment: @KevinDTimm, unless optimized `xx?false:true` is more expensive than `xx^=true`, since it requires a branch prediction and this is not predictable [compared to `instaneceof`] (just telling, you should never assume the compiler is stupid, though)

Comment: @bestsss - I always assume the compiler is not stupid, especially for a hyper-common construct such as this (I would be willing to bet that your code and mine result in exactly the same result in the vast majority of production compilers)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second one is more clear and logical.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer `isShowParameters = !isShowParameters;` because it's shorter.  Shorter programs are easier to understand and maintain.  But what is with your huge clump of unmatched right brackets?  That seems like a bad coding style.

Answer (score 4):

```
ParametersWindows.getInstance().setVisible(!isShowParameters);
```

;)

**Update**

Only works if you don't need the field itself to be updated.

Comment: this doesnt work b/c it does **not** change the field `isShowParameters`

Comment: field value does not change. In the second pressed form disappears.

Comment: Oh, I see. Assuming that it is used somewhere else, then I would go with option #2.

Comment: You can always do `ParametersWindows.getInstance().setVisible(isShowParameters = !isShowParameters);`, although that can get confusing since `= !` looks like `!=`.

Comment: Beautiful. More readable than `isShowParameters ^=true` and shorter than the ternary version.

Answer (score 4):

There is a third option:

```
isShowParameters ^= true;
```

Or more compactly:

```
ParametersWindows.getInstance().setVisible(isShowParameters ^= true);
```